# Access Application Settings Azure Static Web App in Client Side Javascript

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-static-web-app

i created two application settings for my Azure Static Web App through Configuration->Application Settings:
userName = {username};
password = {password};

How do I access them in my index.html webpage using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you don't. They are only available in the backend API.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings):

[image]

Comment: The application settings described in this article only apply to the backend API of an Azure Static Web App.

To configure environment variables that are required to build your frontend web application, see Build configuration.

Any sample for this Build Configuration?

Comment: The docs have one example here. It's up to your build scripts to use the ENV vars that you provide during build https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#environment-variables

Comment: Where do I set the Env variables for the build configuration? is it the same place?